# There is at most one zero of function in given interval.

Tags: real-analysis, summation, special-functions

Let the function $f_{n}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R_{\ge 0}}$ be defined as
$$
f_{n}(x)=\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{i+j}\cos(\ln \frac{i}{j})}{(ij)^{x}}\quad \forall n\in\Bbb N
$$
and let also 
$$
F_{n}(x)=\left(\sqrt{f_{n}(x)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^{x}}\right)^{2} \quad \forall n\in\Bbb N.
$$

> Is it true that for every $n$ equation $F_{n}'(x)=0$ has at most one solution in the interval $x\in(0,1)$?

My idea was to prove that difference between consecutive zeros of given derivative is $\ge 1$
Also i wrote given functions in GeoGebra program for some different $n$ and everything seems to be ok, but I don't know how to check it in general.

Regards.

Comment: $F_n$ will have at most one zero if $\sqrt{f_n(x)} - (n+1)^{-x}$ is monotonic. It may also help to notice that the terms in the sum for $f_n(x)$ are symmetric in $i$ and $j$. I.e., exchanging the values of $i$ and $j$ does not affect the term.